# I need to get the object circles to continue repeat going down the screen, but I'm having trouble finding the right code

Tags: actionscript-3, loops

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event; 


public class rainfall extends MovieClip {


    public function rainfall() {
        // rainfall



        var i:int;
        for (i = 0; i< 50; i++)

        {  
           //variables
            var mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip ();



                //theStage, and alpha properties
                mc.x  = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth ;
                mc.y = Math.random() * 400 * 4 ;
                mc.alpha = Math.random()* 2;
            mc.graphics.beginFill(0x0000FF);
            mc.graphics.drawCircle(0,0,20);
                //trace
                trace(i);


            addChild(mc);
            mc.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveDown) ;
        }

                    function moveDown(e:Event):void
                { //fall speed
                        e.target.y += 1 ;
                }

            }
```

having a lot of trouble trying to figure out how to get the circles to repeat down the screen in a continueous loop, I'm fairly new to actionscript 3 but any tips on what im doing wrong or what I need to get it to loop threw

Comment: after `e.target.y += 1 ;` try `if(e.target.y > stage.stageHeight) e.target.y  = 0;`, so in short, look into conditions. Also consider using a single ENTER_FRAME listener and looping through the display list (e.g. `for(var i:int = 0; i < numChildren; i++) //etc.`)

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza, I think you should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.display.Shape;
import flash.display.DisplayObject;
import flash.events.Event; 


package{

    public class Rainfall extends Sprite {//class names should be title case

        private var numDrops = 50;//this make it easier to configure
        private var dropRadius = 20;
        private var maxY;

        public function Rainfall() {
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,init);//make sure the stage property will not be null
        }

        private function init(event:Event):void{
            maxY = stage.stageHeight;//getters can be slow, store the height so it can be reused for each drop reset
            var i:int;
            for (i = 0; i < numDrops; i++){  
               var mc:Shape = new Shape();//if no interactivity is needed, Shape is the simplest/lightest class to use for drawing
                mc.x  = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth ;
                mc.y = Math.random() * 400 * 4 ;
                mc.alpha = 0.1 + Math.random() * 0.9;//alpha values are from 0 to 1.
                mc.graphics.beginFill(0x0000FF);
                mc.graphics.drawCircle(0,0,dropRadius);
                addChild(mc);
            }
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveDown) ;
        }
        private function moveDown(e:Event):void
        { //fall speed
            for(var i:int = 0 ; i < numDrops; i++){
                var drop:DisplayObject = getChildAt(i);
                drop.y += 1 ;
                if(drop.y > maxY) drop.y = -dropRadius;//if the drop exits the screen downards, place it back at the top (above the visible area)
            }
        }

    }

}
```

It's not tested code, so you might run into syntax errors, but the ideas are commented:

You need to use a conditional for your problem: if the drop's vertical position is greater than the stage's height, then the drop's vertical position should reset back to the top of the stage(`if(drop.y > maxY) drop.y = -dropRadius;a)

Although not necessary if you're just getting started, here are a few tips on efficiency/speed when working in flash:

1. MovieClip is a dynamic class (you can add properties to instances on the fly) but also has a cost. Since you only need to render/draw elements and no events or children are needed, this makes your circles perfect candidates for using the Shape class. Also, your main class can be a Sprite since you're not using a timeline
2. Getters and setters can be a bit slow in actionscript. It's a healthy habbit to cache/store values that don't change much over time for reuse as local variables for faster access.
3. Not as much a performance issue:a common pitfall is not having the stage initialized on a display object, resulting in an annoying and for beginners puzzling null object reference errors. If you use the stage property on a DisplayObject(Shape/Sprite/MovieClip), it's best to make sure it's been added to the stage (and the stage property isn't null) using the `ADDED_TO_STAGE` event

Good luck!